# Import File on Mac (after programming in Python for Windows)

Tags: python, macos, file, pycharm, python-import

I have completed a working, running program in Python on Windows in PyCharm. However, one of the users of this code has a Mac and it does not run without error on their computer. The follow errors appear on their computer: 
[Error that appears on Mac users computer in PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxGqh.png)

This is the line of code that the error refers to in the package 'ep'
[Package we are trying to pull from. Error from line 77.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bjYP.png)

We are importing os, matplotlib, numpy, scipy, and pandas -- therefore 'import os' is not the fix. In addition, this is for sure the correct full path and not the relative path. Any help is apprecaited.

Comment: In the first error image, you have entered the path of some folders from your computer but there are chances the same file in others pc will not be in that path. Did you try to change the path according to the  other person path file

Answer (score 0):

It shows file not found means path of your file is not same as in windows please check the path.